# Cannot clear edittext after setText()

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener, settext

this is my code , but the problem is when the I want to clear some chars i cannot

```
TWL=new TextWatcher(){


            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



            }


            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {


            }


            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                 name.removeTextChangedListener(this);//after this line you do the editing code


               name.setText(s+"-");
               name.setSelection(name.getText().length());



               name.addTextChangedListener(TWL); // you register again for listener callbacks

            }};
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         name.addTextChangedListener(TWL);
```

Comment: Why do you remove the listener and then add it again? it makes no sense. Also I don't see any character removal in your code - all you do is add a hyphen

Comment: Where is your code to delete the chars?

Comment: @Henrique Rocha when i enter backspace I cannot remove the chars

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem: after setting the text with setText the TextWatcher doesn't respond to deletes until more text is entered. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a quite similar problem. I had a EditText with a OnKeyListener, but it did not let me delete any space in the edittext (I didn't listen to any "delete button" event).
I figured out what's wrong when I tried to return "false" in my listener (event not completed). Not it works like a charm. Are you sure you don't have any key listener on that? In that case, do you return false when you "grab" the event?

Hope it helps

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.main_nome)).setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                //hide the keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm= (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(R.id.main_nome).getWindowToken(), 0);

                iniziaClicked(view);
                findViewById(R.id.loseFocus).requestFocus();
            }

            return false;
        }
});
```